# MVC Core добавить объект в базу данных

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Делаю MVC Core приложение, как орм использую EF Core, у меня есть 2 модели

Модель `Game`:

```
public int GameID { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

public decimal Price { get; set; }

public string ImageThumbnail { get; set; }

public int CategoryID { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Модель `Category`:

```
public int CategoryID { get; set; }

public string CategoryName { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
```

Проблема в том, что когда я добавляю в бд новою модель игры, и выбираю ту категорию, которая уже существует, название категории, если я ввожу уже существующую в таблице `Category` то значение в таблице `Category` дублируется, как этого избежать?

Значения добавляю, например, вот так:

```
@model Game
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="GameID" />
    ......
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Category.CategoryName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Category.CategoryName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
.......
</form>
```

Comment: Вместо текстового поля используйте select элемент (Html.DropDownList).

Answer (score 0):

Отправляйте во ViewBag

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(context.Category.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    ......
    }
```

Потом указывает этот ViewBag во вьюхе своей

```
<label asp-for="CategoryId"></label>
<select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Category"></select>
```